# Batch file Python Execution

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a program written in BASIC, and **need it to trigger an external python code by use of a batch file**. However, although the batch file is created, it is clear that my python code is not running - the python file is supposed to create other folders, but nothing is created when I run the code. However, when running my script (`NoArgv.py`) from the shell, it works, so I know the python script is not the problem.

I have made sure to add python to my environment variables path, and made sure that I have full permission/access to the file. Below are the contents from the batch file, `TEST.bat`.

```
"C:\python27\python.exe" "C:\USERS\ELARRICK\DESKTOP\NoArgv.py"
DEL "fst.bat"
```

Is there something specifically wrong with this code? If not, what should I change to make sure that the file runs?

**Disclaimer: The code is written in a slightly altered version of BASIC by my company, so it may look strange - I'll include the main portion of calling the batch file below *just in case* someone understands it

```
' create a batch file
$filehandle = fileopen "C:\USERS\ELARRICK\DESKTOP\TEST.bat", 0
' specify the python exe here
$strglob[29] = "C:\python27\python.exe"
' specify the name of the python program you want to run
$strglob[30] = "C:\USERS\ELARRICK\DESKTOP\NoArgv.py"
' form a long string write to the batch file
$strglob[31] = "\x22"+$strglob[29]+"\x22 " +  "\x22"+$strglob[30]+"\x22"    
' copy the parameter file over to the directory
filewrite $filehandle, $strglob[31]
' this takes care of deleting the batch file
filewrite $filehandle, "DEL \x22fst.bat\x22"
fileclose $filehandle
$filehandle = 0
' execute the batch file
exemodal "C:\USERS\ELARRICK\DESKTOP\TEST.bat"
```

Comment: So the .bat file is created, that's good. Could you add the content of the TEST.bat file? Is TEST.bat being executed? You need to test if TEST.bat is being executed or not, maybe something in the syntax of it is wrong or isn't being executed. Post its content to analyze it.

Comment: @MiguelOrtiz - The content of the actual `TEST.bat` file is shown above (opened in Notepad); because I have never used the batch file format, I am unsure whether I need more in it. However, the reason I believe the .bat file is not being executed is because the comment simply tells the python script, `NoArgv.py` to run. Since I ran the python script from the shell successfully, I know that it does what it is supposed to do. When creating a BASIC code to just run the batch file, however, it doesn't have the same output.

Comment: Let's forget about python one second. Is `exemodal "C:\USERS\ELARRICK\DESKTOP\TEST.bat"` executing the bat? if you add an "echo test" in TEST.bat it get's printed? Is a cmd window being opened?

Comment: I added "echo test", but to answer your question about the cmd window, no. A window breifly appears, but it disappears immediately.

Comment: Maybe take a notice of the location of created folder? (I mean, current working directory)

Comment: @elarr For the brief shown cmd, you may use a `pause` to hold on that window. However, this is slightly out of the original problem.

Comment: @elarr that window is probably the bat being executed, we would want to debug what happens there, so as @GenoChen says add `pause` after `echo 'test'`

Comment: Okay, all I see in the cmd window after that is the 'TEST' echo, then another line that says `press any key to continue`. When I hit enter, of course, the cmd window quits out.

Comment: That's good, it tell us that your .BAT is being executed. Now we can focus on the python execution.  Try adding `print 'this is python'` inside your python script (if python 2.7) or `print ('this is python')` if  python 3, does the python display the string? Don't forget adding `pause` after the python execution in the TEST.bat file.

Comment: @MiguelOrtiz I ended up putting `python NoArgv.py <FILENAME>` into the `.bat' file upon creation and forcing it to just run the python code with arguments included, then put a few ore lines to make sure everything ran smoothly. I basically ran it as if it was another python file written in "command line code" (changing directories, etc.). Not sure why I didn't think of it before, but it seemed to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @elarr that's great! I would have added `%*` instead `<FILENAME>` but I haven't a windows at hand to test: `python NoArgv.py  %*`